# Como puedo hacer un join con la tabla users y otra tabla dependiendo del usuario logueado?

Tags: laravel

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Sistema;
use App\Users;    

public function index()
    {
      $sistema = DB::table('sistema as s')
              ->join('users as u','s.id_sistema','u.id_sistema')
              ->where('u.usuario','=',auth()->user()->usuario)
              ->select('u.usuario','s.descripcion');
    return view('home',compact('sistema'));
    }
```

Este es mi **homecontroller** y lo que quiero es que al acceder desde el login me pueda dar algún valor de la tabla sistema, la cual se conecta con la tabla users, como se muestra anteriormente, si coloco `auth()->user()->usuario` en el **home.blade.php** me aparece el usuario de la tabla usuarios sin ningún problema, pero al colocar el código que tengo me aparece este error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$descripcion
>   (View:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sistema/resources/views/home.blade.php)

**PD. estoy usando laravel 5.8**

Comment: `auth()->user()->usuario` devuelve un objeto? Si es así, probablemente esté mal tu `where`, debería ser algo así `where('u.usuario', '=', auth()->user()->usuario->id)`. Por otro lado, no se si es opcional el operador del `join`: `join('users as u', 's.id_sistema', '=', 'u.id_sistema')`.

Comment: He usado ese método de querys en otras ocasiones pero es la primera vez que lo uso para que me muestre información dependiendo el usuario logeado

Comment: Me imagino usuario es un campo de la tabla user,  por ejemeplo yo uso este en ocaciones Auth::user()->id_usuario eso si teneindo presente incluir 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;